# How to stop this recursive function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, circular-reference

I have javascript array, where each item has reference to parent, and they can be looped (circular reference). Example:

```
[
        {"id": 1, "firstName": "Macko","parentId": 12},
        {"id": 2, "firstName": "Jess","parentId": 1},
        {"id": 3, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 1},
        {"id": 4, "firstName": "Lisa", "parentId": 1},
        {"id": 5, "firstName": "Megan","parentId": 1},
        {"id": 6, "firstName": "John", "parentId": 4},
        {"id": 7, "firstName": "Joe", "parentId": 4},
        {"id": 8, "firstName": "Matthew","parentId": 2},
        {"id": 9, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 2},
        {"id": 10, "firstName": "Dio","parentId": 5},
        {"id": 11, "firstName": "Hello","parentId": 5},
        {"id": 12, "firstName": "Ana", "parentId": 4}
]
```

I needed to create nested data structure based on selected record to display it in the DOM, which I achieved by recursive function like below (source [here](http://oskarhane.com/create-a-nested-array-recursively-in-javascript/))

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
  var out = []
  for(var i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].parent == parent) {
        var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

        if(children.length) {
            arr[i].children = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return out
}
```

It works really well, but not for circular data structures. The thing is I need to stop function execution before it reaches to element from which it started.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: add an argument (e.g. array) that keeps a list of visited IDs so you can check it and stop when appropriate.

Comment: @Cyb3rFly3r I tried that but got wierd or incomplete results. Could you post an example? I propably put condition in wrong place.

Comment: It's unclear what your intended result is since the original code always produces an empty array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `checked` array keeps the `id`s of all the objects (parents) `getNestedChildren` was already called upon.

If the current child's `id` is in that array, do not include it as a child.

```
var arr = [
  {"id": 1, "firstName": "Macko","parentId": 12},
  {"id": 2, "firstName": "Jess","parentId": 1},
  {"id": 3, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 1},
  {"id": 4, "firstName": "Lisa", "parentId": 1},
  {"id": 5, "firstName": "Megan","parentId": 1},
  {"id": 6, "firstName": "John", "parentId": 4},
  {"id": 7, "firstName": "Joe", "parentId": 4},
  {"id": 8, "firstName": "Matthew","parentId": 2},
  {"id": 9, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 2},
  {"id": 10, "firstName": "Dio","parentId": 5},
  {"id": 11, "firstName": "Hello","parentId": 5},
  {"id": 12, "firstName": "Ana", "parentId": 4}
];

var getNestedChildren = function(arr, id, checked) {

  var out = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].parentId === id && checked.indexOf(arr[i].id) === -1) {
      checked.push(id);
      var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id, checked);
      if (children.length) {
        arr[i].children = children;
      }
      out.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return out;

};

console.log(getNestedChildren(arr, 12, []));
```

Comment: Unfortunately for ID:12 it produces only one child, ID 1

Comment: ID 12 indeed has one child ID1. ID1 has four children, they have children and so on until we come back to ID 12.

Comment: You want all the children in the same array? Because the children are found, but are stored in `children` property. All you need is one loop to get them all.

Comment: That's correct, all in the same array until top level parent is found, so in case of ID 12 list should be populated deep down until it encounters ID 12.

Comment: @Ketus You are correct. My code was totally wrong. It's now updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109339/discussion-between-ketus-and-janje).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this should work for you:

```
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent, visited_list) {
  var out = []
  for(var i in arr) {
    if(!(arr[i].id in visited_list) && (arr[i].parentId == parent)) {

        visited_list[arr[i].id] = true;
        var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id, visited_list)

        if(children.length) {
            arr[i].children = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return out
}

nestedList = getNestedChildren(arr, 1, [])
```

Comment: hm i thought it would work but when i start from ID 12, 4 levels deep there's also object with ID 12. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could mark the entries that you have already visited. Based on that you can skip processing the same element twice.

As you are adding the `children` property to the elements, you could use that for this marking purpose, provided you also create this property when an element has no children.

Here is working code doing this:

```js
function getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
  var out = [];
  for(var i in arr) {
    if(arr[i].parentId == parent) {
        if (arr[i].children === undefined) {
            arr[i].children = []
            var children = getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)
            arr[i].children = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return out
}

var arr = [
    {"id": 1, "firstName": "Macko","parentId": 12},
    {"id": 2, "firstName": "Jess","parentId": 1},
    {"id": 3, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 1},
    {"id": 4, "firstName": "Lisa", "parentId": 1},
    {"id": 5, "firstName": "Megan","parentId": 1},
    {"id": 6, "firstName": "John", "parentId": 4},
    {"id": 7, "firstName": "Joe", "parentId": 4},
    {"id": 8, "firstName": "Matthew","parentId": 2},
    {"id": 9, "firstName": "Peter","parentId": 2},
    {"id": 10, "firstName": "Dio","parentId": 5},
    {"id": 11, "firstName": "Hello","parentId": 5},
    {"id": 12, "firstName": "Ana", "parentId": 4}
]

getNestedChildren(arr, 1)

// Output the lengths of the children's arrays
document.body.innerHTML = arr.map(function (item) {
    return 'Item ' + item.id + ' has ' + item.children.length + ' children.'
}).join('<br>')
```